# How to open file chooser in kivy android webview?

Tags: python, kivy

I created a webview app using kivy for android. Using following.

```
from kivy.app import App
from jnius import autoclass
from kivy.clock import Clock
from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

WebView = autoclass('android.webkit.WebView')
WebViewClient = autoclass('android.webkit.WebViewClient')
activity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity

@run_on_ui_thread
def create_webview(*args):
    webview = WebView(activity)
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(True)
    wvc = WebViewClient();
    webview.setWebViewClient(wvc);
    activity.setContentView(webview)
    webview.loadUrl('https://google.com')


class Wv(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.__functionstable__ = {}
        Clock.schedule_once(create_webview, 0)
    

class ServiceApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Wv()
```

Using buildozer I have made apk. But the problem is that when I visit some website and try to upload image using [choose file] button then file chooser window not opeining. I view logcat before click and after click but still not found any log about this.

How can I resovle this issues? How can select image from sdcard and upload it to website opened in webview kivy (android)?

Thanks